# Target <target name> OUTPUT_NAME depends on itself

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am using python's [cmake-converter](https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use.html) in order to generate cmake files from a .sln project.

In visual studio I am trying to generate the cmake files for **WSL-GCC-Debug** configuration.

When Visual Studio starts the CMake generation I get this error

> [CMake] CMake Error at *<path to Example>*/CMakeLists.txt:220 (add_library):
>
> [CMake]   Target '*<Example>*' OUTPUT_NAME depends on itself.

CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
1 set(PROJECT_NAME Example)
2 set(no_group_source_files
...
100 Example.h
...
180 )
181 source_group("" FILES ${no_group_source_files})
182 set(ALL_FILES
183    ${no_group_source_files}
184 )
...
220 add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${ALL_FILES})
```

There was an open issue about this [here](https://github.com/pavelliavonau/cmakeconverter/issues/57) but I don't see an answer that helps my case

I am new to cmake and trying to debug this. Does anyone have any idea why this happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: Looks like somewhere in the code you set `OUTPUT_NAME` property for your library target as a generator expression. And this generator expression depends on that property. See e.g. a file in CMake tests which causes a similar error message: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/1889ed923ea8c2dd204ca38b8109efdf1963c578/Tests/RunCMake/GeneratorExpression/OUTPUT_NAME-recursion.cmake.

Comment: Hello @Tsyvarev,
Maybe the error is generated from this piece of code `$<TARGET_GENEX_EVAL:Example,$<TARGET_PROPERTY:Example,TARGET_NAME_$<UPPER_CASE:$<CONFIG>>>>`
Is there a way to fix it if the cause of the issue is that the generation expression depends on the OUTPUT_NAME property?

Comment: No, this generator expression unlikely causes the error you got. Note, that a generator expression cannot cause the error by itself: This generator expression should be assigned to the target's **property**.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found this solution to the problem.

Edit **Default.cmake** in **CMake** folder (CMake/Default.cmake)

Change

```
create_property_reader("TARGET_NAME")
```

To some other name except TARGET_NAME i.e

```
create_property_reader("TARGET_NAME_1")
```